# How can I test port / IP address combinations?

Tags: bash, netcat

I am trying to put a test together to test multiple ports on multiple IP addresses. I have set up variables for all of the IP addresses and ports.

For instance:

```
$address1=(10.167.0.20 10.167.0.21)
$ports1=(443 80 8080)
```

I need to iterate through these using something like `nc`. How can I do this? I found something like

```sh
for i in $(echo ${address1} | tr "," "\n"); do
    echo -e ${ports1} | xargs -i nc -w 1 -zvn $i {}
done
```

but that does not seem to be working.

Comment: Please format your question properly. Select code with your mouse and click `{}` in the Formatting Toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic*. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays

```
a=( 10.167.0.20 10.167.0.21 )
p=( 443 80 8080 )
for _a in "${a[@]}"
do
    nc -w 1 -zvn $_a "${p[@]}"
done
```